# apache commons-validator alternative for new gTLDS

Tags: java, validation

I need to validate emails and domains. I just need a formal validation, no whois or other forms of domain lookup needed.

Currently I'm using apache's commons-validator v1.4.0

Unfortunately my customers use the new gTLDs, like .bike or .productions that are not yet supported by the DomainValidator class.
See [Apache's Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VALIDATOR-324) for more details.

Are there any sound alternatives that I may easily include in my Maven POM?

Comment: Note for everybody: The Bug has been fixed with version 1.4.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are not concerned about internationalized addresses, you could change last part of address, and continue to use Apache commons.

This approach is based on the fact that whatever the TLD is, the validity of the whole domain name is equivalent to the validity of the same domain name with the TLD replaced with `com`. For example:

- `abc.def.com` is valid. Similarly `abc.def.name`, `abc.def.xx--kput3i`, `abc.def.uk` are valid.
- `ab,de.com` is not valid. Similarly `ab,de.name`, `ab,de.xx-kput3i`, `ab,de.uk` are not valid.

So instead of calling

```
return EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(userEmail);
```

You can call

```
if ( userEmail == null ) {
    return false;
}
return EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(userEmail.trim().replaceFirst("\\.\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alnum}$", ".com"));
```

**Explanation**

- The regular expression `"\\.\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alnum}$"` checks for the TLD part: it's at the end of the string (because of the `$`), it starts with a dot and contains no other dot, and it conforms to the standards: begins with an ASCII Alpha character, followed by zero or more alphanumerics or dashes, and ends with an alphanumeric character.
- I am using `trim()` because until now, if you used `EmailValidator`, it allows spaces before and after the address. Removing the spaces just makes it easier to replace the TLD, and it shouldn't matter as far as the validity of the address is concerned.
- If the string doesn't have a valid TLD at the end, `String.replaceFirst()` will return it as is. It could still be valid, because email addresses of the format `x@[n.n.n.n]` where `n.n.n.n.` is a valid IP address are valid. So basically, if you didn't find a TLD, you let `EmailValidator` decide the validity issue itself.
- Of course, if the TLD is not an IANA recognized TLD, this validation will not tell you that. An e-mail like `david@galaxy.hoopie-frood` will be accepted as legal,but IANA doesn't have that TLD as yet.

Checking a domain is similar, without the `trim()` part:

```
if (userDomain == null ) {
   return false;
}
return DomainValidator.getInstance().isValid(userDomain.replaceFirst("\\.\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alnum}$"));
```

I have also tried JavaMail's email address validation, but I don't really like it: it allows completely invalid domain names such as `net-name.net-` (ending with a dash) or IP addresses (which are not allowed for e-mail without square brackets around them), and it's only good for e-mail addresses, not for domains.

#### Internationalization

If you need to check for internationalized domains and e-mails, it's a bit different. It's easy to check for internationalized domains (for example `元気。テスト`). All you need to do is convert them to ASCII with `java.net.IDN.toASCII()` (yielding `xn--z4qx76d.xn--zckzah` for my example domain - this is a valid TLD), and then do the same as I wrote above.

Internationalized e-mails are a different story. If the local part is ASCII, you can convert the domain part to ASCII. If you have to display the email address, you need to use the Unicode version, and if you have to send an email message, you use the ASCII version.

But recently a standard has been introduced for internationalized local parts as well, which also allows sending to the unicode version of the domain name without translating it to ASCII first. Whether you want to support that or not requires some thought, as not many mail servers and mail transfer agents support it at the moment.

Comment: It is not a drop-in replacement but an explicit workaround that can be removed once the bug is fixed. Thank you

Comment: Note for everybody: The Bug has been fixed with version 1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Copied the implementation from [DomainValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.html) and replaced the `TOP_LABEL_REGEX` expression with `"\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alpha}"`.

In addition, I removed validation against the hard coded list of approved gTLDs. This is, basically, quite weak in that it doesn't validate against the actual domains. But I think it's good enough (catches the gTLDs similar to `XN--YGBI2AMMX`).

See full list of approved gTLDs [here](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

```
// Copied from org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator
private static final String DOMAIN_LABEL_REGEX = "\\p{Alnum}(?>[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alnum})*";
// Changed to include new gTLD - http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
private static final String TOP_LABEL_REGEX = "\\p{Alpha}[\\p{Alnum}-]*\\p{Alpha}";
// Copied from org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator
private static final String DOMAIN_NAME_REGEX = "^(?:" + DOMAIN_LABEL_REGEX + "\\.)+" + "(" + TOP_LABEL_REGEX + ")$";
private static final RegexValidator domainRegex = new RegexValidator(DOMAIN_NAME_REGEX);

private static final EmailValidator EMAIL_VALIDATOR = new EmailValidator();

public static boolean isValidDomain(String domain) {
    String[] groups = domainRegex.match(domain);
    return groups != null && groups.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you use the latest IANA TLD list instead of the hardcoded list? Is there a way to specify which IANA list to use?

Answer (score 0):

What I often do in this situation is to checkout the source code for the library in question (it's open source remember?), modify it to suit my requirement, and then contribute the patch back to the project.

Your use case certainly sounds like it would be a useful contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a [public suffix list Java API](https://github.com/whois-server-list/public-suffix-list). The method [`PublicSuffixList.getRegistrableDomain()`](http://whois-server-list.github.io/public-suffix-list/apidocs/de/malkusch/whoisServerList/publicSuffixList/PublicSuffixList.html#getRegistrableDomain%28java.lang.String%29) can be used for Domain validation:

```
PublicSuffixListFactory factory = new PublicSuffixListFactory();
PublicSuffixList suffixList = factory.build();

assertNull(suffixList.getRegistrableDomain("galaxy.hoopie-frood"));
assertNotNull(suffixList.getRegistrableDomain("example.bike"));
```

Answer (score 0):

While DomainValidator is missing some of the new TLDs, for me the best solution was to update TLD.

```
DomainValidator.updateTLDOverride(ArrayType.COUNTRY_CODE_PLUS, new String[]{"someTLD"});
```

And then initiate EmailValidator Instance

```
EmailValidator.getInstance(false, true)
```